# if data entered in a cell matches a range then execute google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to execute some code based on the entered value in a cell being in a named range.

I've tried something similar to this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
function onEdit() {
    var aSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var aCell = aSheet.getActiveCell();
    var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
    var aDatarange = aSheet.getRange(aCell.getRow(),aColumn);
    var aData = aDatarange.getValue();
    var SomeRange = aSheet.getRangeByName('RangeName');

    if (aData in 'SomeRange') {
        execute some code
    }
}
```

I'm guessing its the if statement I'm doing incorrectly but I've tried `var in range` and `var = range` and neither seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the data out of the range, so that the value from the cell can be searched for in the range data.  I've added a couple of new variables to your code, and included comments about the new lines of code.

```
function onEdit() {
  var dataAsString,rangeData;

  var aSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var aCell = aSheet.getActiveCell();
  var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
  var aDatarange = aSheet.getRange(aCell.getRow(),aColumn);
  var aData = aDatarange.getValue();
  var SomeRange = aSheet.getRangeByName('RangeName');

  rangeData = SomeRange.getValues();//Get the values out of the range
  dataAsString= rangeData.toString();//Convert the 2D array to a a comma seperated string of values

  if (dataAsString.indexOf(aData) !== -1) {//The value of "aData" was found in the data string
    //execute some code
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a followup question if you have the time: Will this work with multiple if statements? I am having trouble getting it to work with aData being indexed in 2 different strings. 1 of the strings only contains 1 thing in it so I don't know if that somehow screws with the toString() command since there's only 1 thing in that range. I just have it as a range of 1 expecting to add more in the future. Only the string with multiple entries works when the input matches.

Comment: You may need to check `rangeData` for a valid value:  `if (!rangeData) {return;}`   Actually, you may need to test other values for a valid value, just in case there is no defined range, or nothing for values in the range.  But I'm not sure what your situation really is.  You may need to ask a separate question.  If you are not familiar with troubleshooting, please read the following [Link to Apps Script documentation for troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)